# Not responding to selector : delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want  to send the information from Players View Controller to Current Match View Controller using a delegate. The only thing is that PlayersViewCotroller and GameDetailsViewController are seperated by another view controller. What should I do to make sure that the selector is being called? Am I missing anything?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class PlayersViewController;
@protocol PlayersViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(PlayersViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringPlayer1:(NSString *)player1 didFinishEnteringPlayer2:(NSString *)player2;
@end

@interface PlayersViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *notes1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *player2;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *notes2;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *nextButton;

- (IBAction)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PlayersViewControllerDelegate> pdelegate;

@end
```

PlayersViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqual:@"playersSegue"]) {

    if([self.pdelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addItemViewController:didFinishEnteringPlayer1:didFinishEnteringPlayer2:)]){

        [self.pdelegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringPlayer1: player1.text didFinishEnteringPlayer2: player2.text];

            NSLog(@"Works");            
    }

}
```

CurrentMatchViewController.m (sending the info to this view controller)

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(PlayersViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringPlayer1:(NSString *)player1 didFinishEnteringPlayer2:(NSString *)player2 {

    NSLog(@"%@", player1);

}
```

Comment: show us where you set the delegate.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the delegate pattern. You can't use it to send data to an object that doesn't exist yet which is what I suspect you are trying to do, but it isn't clear for your question

Comment: Do you think I should use singletons instead?

Comment: @av993 playersviewcontroller - show how you have set the pdelegate property